# How to Install node_modules using node-gyp?

Tags: node.js, opencv, node-gyp

I am trying to install [node-opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) . The repo is successfully build . 
I want the opencv project to be installed as node_module globally .

**Is that possible ?**

I am new to node world.

---

**'*node-gyp rebuild*' is same as '*npm install*' ?**

*Because is built the repo of node-opencv but still my project looks for the dependency for HTTP*

> Answered : by Jonathan Lonowski in his comment.Please read the comments .Really helpful

---

I have opencv as dependency in my project .I have build the repo of opencv But still my project is making http call for opencv dependency.

**I want the build repo to be used .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the opencv project to be installed as node_module globally. Is that possible?

"Global" packages, installed with `-g` or `--global` option, are not [intended to be available for `require()`](https://npmjs.org/doc/folders.html):

> - Install it **locally** if you're going to `require()` it.
> - Install it **globally** if you're going to run it on the command line.

You can, however, install them *locally* to a parent directory. As long as the location can be found following the [rules described for `node_module` folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders), it can be required:

> For example, if the file at `'/home/ry/projects/foo.js'` called `require('bar.js')`, then node would look in the following locations, in this order:
>
> - `/home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/home/ry/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/home/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/node_modules/bar.js`

---

> I have build the repo of opencv But still my project is making http call for opencv dependency.

For this, it would help if you could elaborate on how you've installed the package, including how you're specifying it as a dependency.

But, further HTTP requests should only be needed for packages upon request:

```
# download and build the latest version
npm install opencv

# it should remain at that version until you request an update
npm update opencv
```

Comment: The node-opencv project has used binding.gyp . Installation link says to build repo ."node-gyp rebuild " is same as "npm install" ?

Comment: @saurabhshashank `npm install` will use [`node-gyp rebuild`](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/blob/master/package.json#L14) to finish installing. Typically, you install from repo when your intention is to work on the project itself. Use `npm install` when you want it as a dependency. You can alternatively specify a [dependency by Git URL](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#Git-URLs-as-Dependencies) or use [`npm link`](https://npmjs.org/doc/link.html) after building the repo.

Comment: thanks a lot . I am able to build the repo , but npm install is not working for same project .

Comment: @saurabhshashank Amend: They're not the same; but `node-gyp rebuild` will be called either way (directly by you in the repo or by `npm install` within copy it downloads). Also, "*not working*" how? Do you get an error from the command?

Comment: yup while creating make file :
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o
In file included from ../src/init.cc:4:0:
../src/CascadeClassifierWrap.h:16:35: error: ‘eio_req’ has not been declared
../src/CascadeClassifierWrap.h:17:39: error: ‘eio_req’ has not been declared
make: *** [Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o] Error

Comment: @saurabhshashank There's an issue on the project that reports a similar (if not same) error: https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/issues/41. Seems that it's a compatibility issue between the current release and Node v0.10.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I will try it with node0.8 and update the qus .

Comment: Take a look at nvm (node version manager)  https://github.com/creationix/nvm. nvm makes working with multiple versions of node.js much easier